# apt update and upgrade always fail the second time when I execute Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, apt

I have a ubuntu (16 or 18) EC2 and I use an Ansible playbook to install packages such as rabbitmq. etc on it. The first time when I install I get no error. but if I run playbook the second time I always stopped due to the error at apt-get update and apt-get upgrade. and the error is always (or most of time) related to rabbitmq-server.

Below is a part of my Ansible code. Does anybody know the reason?

```
- name: Update and upgrade apt.
  become_user: root
  apt: update_cache=yes upgrade=dist cache_valid_time=1  
  ...
- name: install rabbitmq-server
  become_user: root
  apt: name=rabbitmq-server state=installed
  ...
```

======== error message is super long and most are just some file code. here I pasted some relevant I think:

```
fatal: [10.X.X.X.X]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "'/usr/bin/apt-get dist-upgrade' failed: E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)\n", "rc": 100, "stdout": "Reading package lists...
…
…
"Setting up erlang-common-test (1:22.0.7-1) ...", "Setting up erlang (1:22.0.7-1) ...", "Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.6.15-1) ...", "Installing new version of config file /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server ...", "Job for rabbitmq-server.service failed because the control process exited with error code.", "See \"systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service\" and \"journalctl -xe\" for details.", "invoke-rc.d: initscript rabbitmq-server, action \"start\" failed.", "* rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker", "   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)", "   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-09-12 12:48:59 PDT; 5ms ago", "  Process: 712 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server \u001b[0;1;31m(code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)\u001b[0m", " Main PID: 712 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)", "dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):", " installed rabbitmq-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1", "Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.29) ...", "Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...", "Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...", "Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...", "Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...", "Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...", "Errors were encountered while processing:", " rabbitmq-server"]}
```

Comment: What is the error message though?

Comment: Thanks PrasadK and user1529891, I have update the post with error message